# Can Pixar USDZ files imported into Blender?

Tags: import, file-format

Can Pixar USD files (USDZ) be imported into Blender?

Comment: Have you solved this problem? I've tried the following add-on and it didn't work: https://github.com/robmcrosby/BlenderUSDZ

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Download the latest version from here: https://github.com/robmcrosby/BlenderUSDZ

In Blender: *Edit > Preferences > Addons > Install > Select the zip* and make sure the add-on is enabled.

---

Related: [How to download and install an add-on hosted on github properly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169234/how-to-download-and-install-an-add-on-hosted-on-github-properly/169235#169235)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. In my case it worked simply by renaming the file with `.usd.zip` extension then unzipping it and importing it as USD in Blender.