# How to download and install an add-on hosted on github properly?

Tags: add-on, installation

I have downloaded an add-on hosted on github today using this green 'Download/Clone' button. However, when I try to install it via *User Preferences > Addons > Install* it **does not appear in the Add-on list**, no matter what I do. 
[image]

**Q:** How to download and install add-ons hosted on github properly? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Option 1 - Follow the instructions

Search for any instructions on **how to install the add-on** in the first place and make sure you follow them step by step (can vary). In most cases those instructions listed in the `README.md` as part of the repository.

---

#### Option 2 - Release version

**Before** downloading the [entire repository](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repository_(version_control)) using the '*Code*' button, make sure there is no actual **release** (In most cases there is, to keep development organized):

[image]

If so, click on *Releases Tab* and download the latest release (`.zip` or single `.py` file):

[image]

Once downloaded, go to *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > Install*, select the file (`zip` or `py` file) and press *Install Add-on* as usual.

[image]

---

#### Option 3 - No release version but `__init.py__` located in the main directory

If there is **no release version**, using the '*Code*' button is the only option to download the add-on. If there is an `__init__.py` file located in the main directory, click the green '*Code*' button and download the zip:

[image]

Once downloaded, go to *Edit > Preferences > Add-ons > Install*, select the file (`.zip` or `.py` file) and press *Install Add-on* as usual.

[image]

**Note:** This way you can also try an **experimental version of the add-on** in case the release version is behind some changes.

---

#### Option 4 - `__init__.py` is part of a subfolder

Search for `__init__.py` in the repository and copy the folder containing this file to your [Add-on directory](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html#blender-s-directory-layout):

- Linux: `$HOME/.config/blender/<version>/`
- OSX: `/Library/Application Support/Blender/<version>/`
- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<version>\`

You can get also get the folder per machine using the [python console](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/python_console.html): `bpy.utils.script_path_user()` and / or `bpy.utils.script_paths("addons")`

Further reading: [Addons: Only some .zips will install](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/39745/31447)

Comment: You literally saved my ass, I spent 4 hours trying to debug this, turns out I was just being a moron.