# Unable to install add-ons to Blender 2.82a and Blender 2.9 on a Mac

Tags: add-on, installation, osx

I am at total loss and YouTube/Google offer nothing to solve this issue.

I downloaded the .zip file for Edge-Flow Master from Github and there is no way to actually install the files.

I've opened up Blender 2.82a and 2.9a) and go through the usual route of opening

Edit>Preferences>Add-ons ensuring Official/Community/Testing are active then click on Install an addon.

I then navigate to the folder in my Downloads but all that is there is; Pyhthon scripts, a doc folder containing jpg and psd files, a License text file and a Readme Text File (neither of the latter will open on my iMac 2011)

I've gone through clicking on each possible python script and clicking install and nothing happens.  So I searched YouTube and there are very few helpful videos or websites going through the process, but I did find one very very annoying video that eventually got to opening Blender in a finder window using Show Package Content then navigating to the addon via Contents>Resources>2.82>Scripts>Addons and then I copied the files to this location rebooted Blender and yet still nothing when I search for the addon proving it's not installed.

So just how am I to install addons to Blender without a .zip file to install from (Apparently it just dumped the files to my download folder I assume it unzipped itself in doing that)?

I don't know enough about addons or python to know how to properly get Blender to recognise these files there's no installer and no .zip file and directly coping the files to the addon folder does nothing.

So I am at a lost.  I've used Blender years ago but I don't remember if I ever came across this issue before, or maybe I did but have forgotten.

I'd like to purchase some modelling addons but I'm not laying down hard cash until I can resolve this addon installation propblem. This isn't the first addon Ive had this problem with I also downlaoded WrappingTools - same issue, no way to install it.

Comment: The installation process of any add-on is os independent. Go to add-ons, install from file, selected the downloaded zip file and it will install automatically (no reboot required, even no restart of blender). However, you have to download the correct zip file... read the link above.

Comment: Also, remember that Blender 2.9 is an Alpha version, which means that not every add-on is going to work.

Comment: The trouble is that when I download from Github I'm not seeing a zip file, just a folder full of .py files.  So there is no zip file to install from within the Preferences of Blender .  I did expressly state "...there's no installer and no .zip file and directly coping the files to the addon folder does nothing."

Answer (score 1):

The installation process is detailed under [the GitHub page](https://github.com/BenjaminSauder/EdgeFlow#installation) and is the same as most if not all add-ons.

Download the zip file from the [releases page](https://github.com/BenjaminSauder/EdgeFlow/releases). Open Blender, open up *Preferences*, click on *Add-On* tab, press *Install* and select the zip file. You'll then be able to find the add-on listed as Mesh: EdgeFlow. I tested it. It works.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I noticed that this question comes up frequently so I created a more generalized post on how to install add-ons hostet on github: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/169234/31447 Feel free to submit. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for the comments I have found a workaround but I'm puzzled why I had to do it such a way.  I downloaded as I had done previously from Github the .zip file but it seems to automatically extract in doing so.  However, I right clicked again on the github link on Download Zip using "Download Linked File as..." and located my desktop rather than the download folder.  This time the zip file was in tact and I was able to install.  No idea why the zip files are auto extracting to my Download folder.  But using "Downlaod Linked File As..." seems to do the trick.