# I Cannot make GIS Blender 2.82 Addon for Windows work

Tags: add-on

I am not sure what I did wrong during the process of installing the GIS add-on, but for some reason even after unchecking and rechecking its checkbox in Preferences, there is still no sign of any sort of GIS option in Blender. Not even if I searched it in the "Operator Search".

Also, is the GIS add-on able to work with both Cycles and Eevee? I tried switching between the two, but nothing happened. If you have any suggestions for what I could do to fix this issue, please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure that you've downloaded the correct .zip file, see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169234/how-to-download-and-install-an-add-on-hosted-on-github-properly).

Comment: I downloaded the correct .zip file, but not until now I did not know all of the steps for how to actually install an add-on. After downloading the .zip file, I just had to hit Install in Preferences, then select the .zip file.