# How to install lsystem add-on?

Tags: add-on, installation

Apologies if this seems very basic, but I am really struggling with how to do this and am not sure where I am going wrong.

I have a found an L-System addon on Github (https://github.com/krljg/lsystem) that I am trying to use in Blender.

I have tried downloading the .zip file and saving within my Blender Installation: C:\Desktop\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.82\2.82\scripts\addons but I cannot find it when I install the file in User Preferences -> addons.

I have tried installing both the .zip folder and extracting it then installing the .init file but nothing shows up in the addons.

Is there something I am missing or doing wrong? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett This is not always true for zip files from Github - it depends on how the folder directory is structured. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install

Comment: Does this help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [readme.md](https://github.com/krljg/lsystem#installation), you would have to copy the **lsystem** folder to your add-on directory:

> **Copy lsystem directory** over to F:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\Blender\2.80\scripts\addons or wherever your blender installation is.

- Linux: `$HOME/.config/blender/<version>/`
- OSX: `/Library/Application Support/Blender/<version>/`
- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\<version>\`

[image]

*Link to the manual for reference:* https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html#blender-s-directory-layout

Comment: also available via `bpy.utils.script_path_user()` and / or `bpy.utils.script_paths("addons")`

Comment: Cool, added to: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/169235/31447 @batFINGER