# Orient Custom Shape addon stopped working in versions above 2.9?

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, rigging, axis

Unfortunately the *Orient bone shapes* add-on either downloaded from [GitHub](https://github.com/scaredyfish/orient_bone_shapes) or from [developer.blender.org](https://developer.blender.org/F207430) does not work anymore for whatever reason.

I have tried to install those scripts on Blender 2.90.0 and 2.93.1,
namely `orient_custom_shape_V2.py` and `orient_custom_shape.py`. But unfortunately all the script gives me same error

> "Upgrade to 2.8x required".

For now I manually orient the object's origin as per the bone axis and then reshape the custom shape. But it takes a lot of time...

**Q:** What can I do in order to get the add-on work again?

Comment: As the error message suggests: The add-on needs to be updated to work with 2.8+ - has nothing to do with your OS rather Blender itself: https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons. Please provide a link to the add-on so we do not need to search for it. Even better: file a bug report (or a request in this case) on github.

Comment: Many thanks for your quick reply, I have changed the value as "blender": (2, 80, 0) inside  bl_info in the python script "orient_custom_shape_V2.py", originally it was "blender": (2, 6, 3). Now when I install this script the error "Upgrade to 2.8x required" does not come. But the goal does not fulfill, means "Orient Bone Shape" button does not come up in pose mode, nightery in view port display ->custom shape, nor in pose context menu (by pressing 'w' button in pose mode).tried all version. Links are, https://developer.blender.org/F207430 , https://github.com/scaredyfish/orient_bone_shapes

Comment: If there is a version for 2.8+ already: https://github.com/scaredyfish/orient_bone_shapes install it as is. You do not have to change anything. If this one is not working for whatever reason, I'd suggest file a bug report.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have tried the script provided in the link given by you, but the same error "Upgrade to 2.8x required", Hence I have file a bug report in GitHub. Thank you for your valuable time and response.

Comment: I don't get this error. See: [How to download and install an add-on hosted on github properly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169234/how-to-download-and-install-an-add-on-hosted-on-github-properly).

Comment: Do not download only one if the scripts. Click on the green code button, download it, install the add-on via add-on preferences (as usual) and it is working fine, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MF6fD.png

Comment: Thank you for your help, It worked finally, The mistake, I was unzipping it and then trying to install it. But the link you provided was very helpful. I followed those steps and the option "align bone shape" come up in pose context menu. Many thanks for your valuable time and appropriate guide. The problem is resolved.