# Custom shape orientation for bones in Blender 2.93

Tags: rigging, shape-keys

I'm following Darin Lile's tutorial and I faced an issue with custom shape orientation for bones.
***https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=miphUq4uwNM&list=PLyelx0TsmSpcgsINPt6fOh3yWjTjk2Nz9&index=9&t=50s***

In the video he uses orient_custom_shape Python script. I searched the Internet and found couple more of them but they're all for 2.8 and lower versions.
Do you know the alternative way to orient shape to bone in Blender 2.93? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution here: [Orient Custom Shape addon stopped working in versions above 2.9?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/228843/orient-custom-shape-addon-stopped-working-in-versions-above-2-9)
I put the folder containing **init**.py in Blender addons path and orient custom shape installed successfully for 2.93