# How to install TubeTool add-on/ make tubes?

Tags: modeling, add-on

[image]So I decided to make some tubes. In the olden days I used to add a bezier curve I could convert or whatever, but now all I get from a bezier curve is a single path. Than I stumbled over this https://github.com/zeffii/TubeTool on youtube. What are the right exact steps to do that? I opened the zipfile and clicked on the elements...nothing happened. Do I need to "go to file" or what? I´m using a mac by the way.

Comment: You really don't need an addon to create pipes. See this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ve9h7-E8EuM for instance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to download and install an add-on hosted on github properly?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/169234/how-to-download-and-install-an-add-on-hosted-on-github-properly)

Comment: @MartyFouts Sorry, don't get it. What's wrong?

Comment: Yep, has been renamed to 'Code', I took care of it. Better? Could you please add the proper windows path? Linux here... Win 10 should be good. @MartyFouts

Comment: @MartyFouts "download the zip" is already part of 3, should we make it bigger? In this case there is a release available that's the way to go so I don't see why to rewrite the post massively. It's hard to cover all cases but I think that's a good start. The paths for linux and OSX are fine. What tool has changed? What answer to which problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133597/discussion-between-marty-fouts-and-p2or).

Comment: That youtubelink above is pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

You can install [TubeTool](https://github.com/zeffii/TubeTool) in 2.93 and it will work fine.

- Go the [TubeTool GitHub repository](https://github.com/zeffii/TubeTool)
- Click on the "Code" button and select "Download ZIP" and download the file TubeTool-master.zip
- In Blender edit your preferences, go to addons and select *Install*
- Navigate the file browser to the folder where you downloaded the file and select TubeTool-master.zip
- Eventual the Tube Tool Entry will show up.  Enable it:

  [image: Tube Tool Enabled in preferences Add-ons]

To use the tool you must be in edit mode.  The web site says it uses the "W" menu, but in 2.93 that's actually the *Right Click* context menu.  Tube Tool should be the first entry.  It's called "Add Tubing".

[image: Add Tubing in the right click context menu]

Everything seems to work as described in the README.md file.